Disney TV series about a kid who's math teacher lives next door
There was a Disney TV series in the 00's based on school kid whose math teacher (or may be class teacher) lived next door.
I do remember there was something to do with baseball.

This does sound like Boy Meets World, with the neighbor/teacher being Mr. Feeny, but baseball wasn't an integral part of it.

I'd vote for Boy Meets World as well ... it wasn't produced by Disney (although its sequel is), but it was a precursor to the style of show that you see on the Disney Channel now (some have argued that the Disney Channel has taken the place of the 90s TGIF). What's more, baseball was an integral part of the first season -- half the episodes had references, and several were completely centered on the Phillies. See here for more details: http://withleather.uproxx.com/2012/11/sports-on-tv-boy-meets-worlds-20-greatest-sports-moments#page/2

@Arbaaz If a week or two goes by and no one has posted the answer as more than a comment. Then I suggest posting the answer yourself and giving credit to Oliver_C and jlmcdonald. That way it's answered.

@KevinHowell yup i'll do that. Strange isnt it?

sned me an @ when a proper answer is posted, i want to clean these comments up.

oliver_c:

This does sound like Boy Meets World, with the neighbor/teacher being Mr. Feeny, but baseball wasn't an integral part of it

jlmcdonald:

I'd vote for Boy Meets World as well ... it wasn't produced by Disney
  (although its sequel is), but it was a precursor to the style of show
  that you see on the Disney Channel now (some have argued that the
  Disney Channel has taken the place of the 90s TGIF). What's more,
  baseball was an integral part of the first season -- half the
  episodes had references, and several were completely centered on the
  Phillies. See here for more details:
  http://withleather.uproxx.com/2012/11/sports-on-tv-boy-meets-worlds-20-greatest-sports-moments#page/2


putting this here to preserve the answer in case he doesn't come back.  If he does then i'll delete this.
